# Copying multiple excel columns one after another with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, merge

I'm using powershell to manipulate a group of excel files. I'm copying one column from each file into another file that will contain all the data. The problem is I need to copy the columns one after another.

I have managed to write this to copy a column and paste it to another excel file.

```
ForEach ($item in $files) { 
$FullName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$item")

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($Path + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$item"))
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1).EntireColumn
$range.Copy() | out-null

$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.item($merge)
$Range = $Worksheet.Range($range2)
$Worksheet.Paste($range)  

$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.Close()
$Excel.quit()
}
```

Comment: Where in the code do you get `$range1` an where do you get the new value for `$range2` after pasting?

Comment: @Theo ```$range1``` is not assigned yet but it's just the range of the column I want to copy. ```range2``` is the value I don't know how to assign since I have to paste the values of the columns one after the other, meaning, all in the same column.